# Inner join 3 tables with only specific columns selected

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I cannot solve this issue, I have tree tables, inner join and I'm after selecting only specific columns because I'm concerned about performance issue if I *just leave SELECT* * *to do the job*.

I have tables: `ugovori-artikli`, `ugovori` and `ids`, **working SELECT * query**:

```
SELECT * FROM `ugovori-artikli`
INNER JOIN `ugovori`
ON `ugovori-artikli`.`ugovor_id` = `ugovori`.`id`
INNER JOIN `ids`
ON `ugovori`.`kupac_id` = `ids`.`id`
AND `ugovori-artikli`.`artikal` = ?
```

and **non-working query, my attempt:**

```
SELECT a.*,
b.*,
c.id, c.ime, c.prezime
FROM `ugovori-artikli` AS a
INNER JOIN `ugovori` AS b
ON `ugovori-artikli`.`ugovor_id` = `ugovori`.`id`
INNER JOIN `ids` AS c
ON `ugovori`.`kupac_id` = `ids`.`id`
AND `ugovori-artikli`.`artikal` = ?
```

I get an error:

```
Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'ugovori-artikli.ugovor_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: use table aliases in the on clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the alias name

```
  SELECT a.*,
    b.*,
    c.id, c.ime, c.prezime
    FROM `ugovori-artikli` AS a
    INNER JOIN `ugovori` AS b
    ON a.`ugovor_id` = b.`id`
    INNER JOIN `ids` AS c
    ON b.`kupac_id` = c.`id`
    AND a.`artikal` = ?
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the aliasses not the table name in your SQL statement.

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.id, c.ime, c.prezime
FROM `ugovori-artikli` AS a
INNER JOIN `ugovori` AS b ON a.`ugovor_id` = b.`id`
INNER JOIN `ids` AS c
ON b.`kupac_id` = cid`
AND a.`artikal` = ?
```